# referring to arrays as pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I can't seem to understand the difference between the different declarations on an array or a 2d array.
for instance:

```
void swap(char **a, char **b) {
    char *t = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = t;
}
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char a[] = "asher";
    char b[] = "saban";
    swap(&a,&b);
}
```

this code doesn't compile, it outputs:

```
warning: passing argument 1 of ‘swap’ from incompatible pointer type
test.c:10: note: expected ‘char **’ but argument is of type ‘char (*)[6]’
```

isn't `a` a pointer to first cell of char array and `&a` is a pointer to pointer?

another example is:

```
char (*c)[3];  
char (*d)[3];  
swap(c,d);
```

doesn't compile either.. is `char (*c)[3]` same as a pointer to `char a[] = "ab"` ?

However this does compile:

```
char *c[3];
char *d[3];
swap(c,d);
```

so i'm totally confused. Why is there a difference? Is there some rules about that issue to prevent me from mistaking all the time?

Thank you all

Comment: This is the second time we've seen this code in three days: [Swapping two string pointers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3816233/). If, by chance this is because you are sharing a class with bass, you might want to get together with him for mutual aid...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think that this is the source of your confusion.

An array variable is a fixed object. It refers to a fixed set of array members. It cannot be changed, although the values of the array members can.

In all expression contexts other than as the argument to unary `&` (address of) and `sizeof` an array will decay into a pointer to its first element.

Given:

```
char a[] = "asher";
```

The expression `a` will decay to a pointer to char (`char*`) and will point to the first character of `a`.

The expression `&a` is a pointer to an array of char (`char (*)[]`). It is a pointer to the complete array rather that a pointer to the first character. It is a different type to a pointer to the first character of the array although it will have the same value as a pointer to the first character of the array.

However, neither of the expressions `a` and `&a` are *lvalues*, they are temporary pointer values.

You cannot swap arrays, you can only swap pointers but to do this you need *lvalue* pointers whose address you can take.

```
void swap(char **a, char **b);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char a[] = "asher";
    char b[] = "saban";
    char* pa = a;
    char* pb = b;
    swap(&pa, &pb);
}
```