# Automatic type casting of array pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am trying to understand pointers and arrays with the following program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int *ptr = &arr;
    int *ptr1 = arr;
    int (*ptr2)[5] = &arr;
    int (*ptr3)[5] = arr;
    int *ptr4 = &arr[0];
    int (*ptr5)[5] = &arr[0]; 
    printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d\n",*(ptr+1), *(ptr1+1), *(ptr2+1), 
            *(ptr3+1), *(ptr4+1), *(ptr5+1));
    return 0;
}
```

In one of the previous questions, [referring to arrays as pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842701/referring-to-arrays-as-pointers), I read that `arr` is a pointer to the first element where as `&arr` is a pointer to the entire array.

If we do pointer arithmetic on `ptr` and `ptr1` as shown in the above program, they both yield the same results i.e both of them are pointers to integer because they are assigned to the variables of type `int *`.

However I created a pointer to an array of 5 elements `ptr2` and assigned the value of &arr. If I try to increment ptr2, it is incremented by 5 elements as expected. The behavior is similar in case of `ptr3`, `ptr4`, and `ptr5`

[Edit] When I do `int *ptr = &arr` the pointer to the array is type casted to `int *` automatically? 
Can I assume that `&arr, arr, &arr[0]` expressions are actually same because they produce the same value? And the arithmetic on this value actually depends on the type of assigned variable?

Comment: `int *ptr = &arr;` using ptr is undefined behavior. The same is true for `int (*ptr3)[5] = arr;` and `int (*ptr5)[5] = &arr[0];` Just sayin.

Comment: Do you mean to say, it is not defined in the standard?

Comment: Compiling your program produces [lots of warnings](http://ideone.com/gWobeX), which should be treated as errors.

Comment: @RaviChandra No, he means to say the results of listed operations cannot be predicted and are therefore undefined.

Comment: Also please pick a single language.

Comment: Here is the link to ideone http://ideone.com/1DzrU1

Comment: @RaviChandra undefined behavior means a very specific thing in C (and other language standards). In short it means that when you have undefined behavior in your program there is no way to predict any behavior of the program. It's simply not valid C anymore. The compiler is allowed to do anything.

Comment: @RaviChandra And this is what happens if you don't ignore warnings: https://ideone.com/bR2CFK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, no, `&arr`, `arr`and `&arr[0]` are not the same. To elaborate,

- `&arr` is the pointer to the array, the whole array. You can refer to the data type, for better understanding. `&arr` is of type `int (*) [5]` here, i.e., the pointer to an array of 5 `int`s.
- `arr` is the array name, which in *certain cases*, decay to the pointer to the first element of the array.
- `&arr[0]` is the address of the first element of the array, under all circumstances.

***Suggestion:*** enable all compiler warnings and it should tell you where you are going wrong.

So, according to the above understanding,

```
 int *ptr = &arr;
```

is wrong as they are not of compatible type. Same goes for

```
int (*ptr5)[5] = &arr[0];
```

hence, any operation you try to perform with those variables (and their results, if any) are not defined.

Answer (score 0):

No, &arr and  arr are not same in C as arr is pointer to first element of arr and &arr is the pointer to arr itself. However arr and &arr[0] are acts as same as they both point to first element of array(still they are not exactly same). In other way you can understand is **arr and &arr[0] point to a 4 byte location whereas &arr point to 5x4 bytes location hence they are different.**