# Swap two strings in C++

Tags: c++, string

I have to swap two strings. This is my code:

```
void swap(char *x, char *y) {
    char tmp;
    tmp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = tmp;
}

char a[20] = "car";
char b[20] = "hotel";

swap(a, b);
```

The program returns har - cotel. Why?

Where is the error? I need hotel - car.

Comment: Because you're only swapping the first `char` of each string. If you're programming in C++, why aren't you using `std::string`?

Comment: I know this, but i have to create a funcion. I cant use a library

Comment: you can't use the standard library? Or it's not C++ maybe?

Comment: If you can use std library, have a look at http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c-program-swap-two-strings or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3816233/swapping-two-string-pointers

Comment: I think that is not even valid because you are modifying a string literal. Isn't that undefined behavior? Your strings should have type `char const*`

Comment: Can you use the c libraries e.g. `strlen`, `strcpy` and the like?

Answer (score 9):

In C++11, just call `std::swap`:

```
std::swap(a, b);
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/oKG7ky)

Answer (score 1):

You should have:

```
void swap(char* &x, char* &y){
    char* tmp = x
    x=y
    y = tmp.
}
```

on swap.

tmp, x, and y are pointers. They have an address inside them and point at a place in memory. You want to exchange the addresses on them.

Edit: But ask around. This has been answered before.

Comment: Please give `tmp` a data type

Answer (score 1):

This is the simple solution:

```
void swap(char a[], char b[])
{
   char tmp[20];
   strcpy(tmp, a);
   strcpy(a, b);
   strcpy(b, tmp);
}
```

Comment: Let's hope that your strings are never longer than 20 chars. Why don't you use `std::string`? Then it is just `std::swap(s1,s2)` for two strings `s1` and `s2`.

Comment: because i need to create a function, i cant use standard library

Comment: So this is some exercise or homework? If this is the case, I would not accept your solution because I'd probably want to see a loop over the strings. Otherwise, if you have the choice (and use C++), use std::string and not C strings.

Comment: Change your prototype to `void swap(char (&a)[20], char (&b)[20])` to be correct.

Answer (score -1):

Because you using char to swap char* string values. In your case, `char tmp = *x` means taking the first char from the x string, meaning `tmp = x[0]`.

All further processing is done on the first char of your string. So it is swapping only the first char's... If you want to swap whole strings then change the function like below:

```
 char* tmp = x;
 x = y;
 y = tmp;
```